# Android LiveData in Transformation map is null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-livedata-transformations

I am facing and issue with Android LiveData and Transformation map. I am gonna explain the case:

I have a SingleLiveEvent and LiveData as follows (one for all items and another one for items to display in screen):

```
val documents: SingleLiveEvent<List<DocumentData>> = SingleLiveEvent()

val itemsToDisplay: LiveData<List<DocumentData>>
        get() {
            return Transformations.map(documents) { documents ->
                return@map documents.filter { showOptionals || it.isMandatory }
            }
        }
```

In Fragment, after observing `itemsToDisplay`, if I am trying to get the value of `itemsToDisplay` LiveData (`itemsToDisplay.value`) is always null

````
itemsToDisplay.observe(this, Observer {
    // Inside this method I need to get a calculated property from VM which uses 
    ```itemsToDisplay.value``` and I would like to reuse across the app
    loadData(it)
})

// View Model
val hasDocWithSign: Boolean
        get() {
            return **itemsToDisplay.value**?.any { it.isSignable } ?: false
        }
````

Does anyone know if a LiveData does not hold the value if it is calculated using `Transformation.map` or it could be a potential bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `itemsToDisplay` you get a new empty LiveData instance, because you declared it as a getter without a backing field.

```
val itemsToDisplay: LiveData<List<DocumentData>>
        = Transformations.map(documents) { documents ->
                documents.filter { showOptionals || it.isMandatory }
        }
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields

Comment: First of all, many thanks for the response!! I did not know about that... But I have one doubt, if I change it to ```var```, how would you declare the initialization or the setter in order to keep LiveData value?

Comment: @Alejandro why do you need `var` and setter if you need to keep LiveData value?

Comment: hmm if I understood well backing fields I need to change it to `var`, otherwise it will not keep LiveData value as it happens now

Comment: @Alejandro use code from my answer, it will create backing field

Comment: Many thanks for it! It worked! Sorry, I did not read properly your answer, got it. Again, thank you so much for investing the time for explaining it!